# Add an existing WebPart Using the Sharepoint client object Model

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010, web-parts, sharepoint-clientobject

My knowledge of the Client Object model is fairly limited, although I have been able to remove and move existing web-parts on a particular page. But I'm now struggling to find and then add a custom web part programmatically using the SharePoint Client Object Model.

The web-part I'm trying to find resides in the Miscellaneous category. I know this by clicking
"Page"-->"Edit Page"-->then clicking "Add a Web Part" in one of the zones. Two list boxes appear on the page: one with a heading Categories and another with a heading Web Parts.

So I'm trying to get a web-part in a category named "Miscellaneous" and then I would like to add it to the right hand side of the default.aspx of my sharepoint site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone stumbles upon this question -I asked the question on the stackexchange - sharepoint and got and anwser that resolved my issue here:https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/79579/add-an-existing-webpart-using-the-sharepoint-client-object-model